# Javascript Date (Time part) wrong when passed to Web Api controller

Tags: javascript, datetime, asp.net-web-api

So the title might not be the best wording.. So i'll demonstrate with images.

I am, in Javascript, creating a `Date`. I then set this `Date`'s hours and minutes.

I then pass this to a Web Api controller. When the date gets to the controller, the time part is off - by the GMT Offset on my machine.

So here, Console shows that I selected the time 10:00am. This is the time I want to see on the server

[image: Console shows that I selected the time 10:00am]

By the time it gets to the server, I get this in my controller - the GMT has been applied somewhere or other...:

[image]

My question is how to I prevent this? I wish to pick a date from a calendar and thena time from dropdowns. I want this time to the passed through to the Web Api without changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript will correct to your local time, this is the root for many problems like this. You see that your time is exactly 5 hours off (10+5 = 15 = 3pm), which happens to be your timezone.

Make sure that the time you send to Javascript is corrected to UTC, then Javascript will convert it automatically for you to your local time.

Comment: Ok thanks :) - having issues the other way around now - I get a UTC from the sever, and I want the hours - by the time I have that in Javascript it applies the ****** GMT again...

Comment: ...and just found getUTCHours instead of getHours for that

Comment: Is there any way to stop javascript to change my selected time,I am using Angular4